# Wp all-in-one-seo plugin - canonical url

Tags: wordpress

I removed the category base from permalinks by placing a dot in the "category base" field.

Now when using all-in-one seo plugin the canonical url shows like this : http://www.domain.com/./my_category/

How can i remove the dot from there to make it show like this "http://www.domain.com/my_category/"

Thank you.

Comment: If you're not opposed to adding in canonical URLs via a simple PHP function in your header.php, you could always turn off canonical URLs in All-in-one-SEO, and do it that way.

Comment: yes, it will work, but .. i tought maybe i could find a simple fix here. thank you